# Left join retornando registros a mais

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Tenho uma tabela principal com cerca de 5.000 registros, e preciso buscar informações em outra tabela com 7.000 registros.

Porém minha consulta esta retornando +6.000:

```
SELECT principal.id, info.nome, info.endereco, principal.valor
FROM principal
LEFT JOIN info
   ON info.usuario = principal.usuario
```

O que pode está acontecendo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `LEFT JOIN`, por definição, traz as linhas da tabela mesmo que elas sejam nulas.

O que é provável de estar acontecendo no seu caso é que nem todas as linhas da tabela `principal` possuem linhas correspondentes na tabela `info`. Além disso, alguns registros da tabela `principal` devem possuir mais de uma linha na tabela `info`.

Answer (score 1):

Pode ser que não haja registros na tabela `info` para todos os registros da tabela `principal`, mas ainda assim os 5 mil registros desta irão aparecer, pois o `left join` é na verdade um `left outer join`.

Não existe `left inner join` ou `right inner join`, pois `inner join` é sempre bidirecional, ou seja, deve haver correspondência nas duas tabelas para a condição de junção.

A diferença de mil linhas dá-se provavelmente porque uma parcela dos registros da tabela `principal` possui dois ou mais registros correspondentes na tabela `info`.